# Ajax to post html form to Java and Rest API to receive it

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, rest

I'm a novice in the field of JavaScript and JQuery. I'm trying out my hands on a project in which I could not pass the form data from HTML using Ajax. Please let me know where I have gone wrong. Here are the details.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <title>Datasheet Generation</title>
     
    <head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href= "css_for_index.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">    
    
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    function callvalue(){
            var formData = JSON.stringify($(#myForm).serializeArray());
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/",
        data: formData,
        success: function(){
                    console.log(formData);
        },
        error: function (error) {
                    console.log(`Error ${error}`);
                },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType : "application/json"
        }); 
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    
<form id = "myForm" method = "post" onsubmit= "callvalue()">    
<table class="table">

  
  <tr>
        <td>Revision :</td>
        <td><input type = "text" id="revision"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>Project Name :</td>
        <td><input type = "text" id="projectName"/></td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>Product Description :</td>
        <td><input type = "text" id="prodDesc"/></td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>Product Code :</td>
        <td><input type = "text" id="prodCode"/></td>
    
  </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>Packing :</td>
        <td><input type = "text" id="packing"/></td>
   </tr>  
    
</table>
<br>
<button class="Gen_Button" type="submit">Generate Datasheet</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class DataSheetGenController {
    
      @PostMapping(value ="/submit", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
      public String getProject(@RequestBody Project project) {
      
      System.out.println("Hello");
      return "submit";
      }
     
}
```

Model class:

```
public class Project {
    
    private String revision;
    private String projectName;
    private String prodDesc;
    private String prodCode;
    private String packing;
    
    public String getRevision() {
        return revision;
    }
    public void setRevision(String revision) {
        this.revision = revision;
    }
    public String getProjectName() {
        return projectName;
    }
    public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    public String getProdDesc() {
        return prodDesc;
    }
    public void setProdDesc(String prodDesc) {
        this.prodDesc = prodDesc;
    }
    public String getProdCode() {
        return prodCode;
    }
    public void setProdCode(String prodCode) {
        this.prodCode = prodCode;
    }
    public String getPacking() {
        return packing;
    }
    public void setPacking(String packing) {
        this.packing = packing;
    }
}
```

I got an exception like the one below, when I clicked on the submit button.

Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

Please help me resolve the issue

Comment: You're not calling what you mapped; you're ajaxing to `/`.

Comment: I tried changing the ajax call from '/' to '/submit'. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are doing well and good.

Replace your script code from below and remove `method="post" and onsubmit= "callvalue()"` in form tag.
And also add ajax cdn before below script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'post.php',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    alert('form was submitted');
                }
            });

        }); </script>
```